# Create custom channefactory for dynamically calling workflows

Tags: wcf, dynamic, workflow-foundation-4, channelfactory

I need to create a custome channel factory for calling WCF Wrokflow services hosted in the IIS. At runtime only i will be able to know which workflow should be called and which method need to be called.
Can anyone help with an example for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What information about the workflow service(s) do you have at the client? If you have the contract (service contract, such as one generated by svcutil / add service reference when pointed to the xamlx service) and the endpoint address, then you can simply use the channel factory directly. For example, the default "WCF Workflow Service Application" declares an endpoint at the xamlx address, with basicHttpBinding.

```
string address = "http://localhost:27962/Service1.xamlx";
Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(address);
IService proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
var result = proxy.GetData(new GetDataRequest { @int = 1234 });
```

If you don't have the contract / binding, you only have the xamlx address, and you want to create a proxy dynamically at runtime, you can use something like [Vipul's dynamic proxy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vipulmodi/archive/2006/11/16/dynamic-programming-with-wcf.aspx) to create the proxy during runtime, and call the service operations using the dynamic proxy methods.

Answer (score 0):

Vipuls dynamic proxy (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vipulmodi/archive/2006/11/16/dynamic-programming-with-wcf.aspx) work perfectly..
Thanks man..